# Bootstrap nested col wont stretch full height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 columns all in a row, each with a nested row and 3 more columns.

```
.row
    .col

        .row
            .col
            .col <-- needs to be full height
    .col
        .row
            .col
            .col <-- needs to be full height
    .col
        .row
            .col
            .col <-- needs to be full height
```

[image]

As you can see, the middle column is not stretching the full height

I tried `align-items-stretch` and `h-100` but no luck.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Full code here

```
        <div class="container bg-secondary pt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col mx-5 px-5">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <img src="/imgs/1.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 bg-light">
                        <p>Submitting an issue through Orem 311 is a great way to get the ball rolling.</p>
                        <p>Submitting an issue through Orem 311 is a great way to get the ball rolling.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col mx-5 px-5">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <img src="/imgs/2.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 bg-light">
                        <p>Submitting an issue through Orem 311 is a great way to get the ball rolling.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col mx-5 px-5">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <img src="/imgs/3.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 bg-light">
                        <p>Submitting an issue through Orem 311 is a great way to get the ball rolling.</p>
                        <p>Submitting an issue through Orem 311 is a great way to get the ball rolling.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's FlexBox Utilities for this.

1. Give the `.row` under `.col.mx-5` these classes: `row flex-row h-100`.
2. Give the `.col-12`, which is supposed to be small, `flex-shrink-1` class.
3. Give the `.col-12`, which is supposed to be longer, `h-100 flex-grow-1` class.

Full Code:

```
<div class="col mx-5 px-5">
  <div class="row flex-row h-100">
    <div class="col-12 flex-shrink-1">
      <img src="/imgs/2.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 bg-light flex-grow-1 h-100">
      <p>Submitting an issue through Orem 311 is a great way to get the ball rolling.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have checked it and it works.

Comment: Thank you!  I had to also add `h-100` to the `flex-grow-1` column and it worked!

Comment: @Barrard Yayyy! `:D` It's all about trial and errors.

Comment: Would you mind adding that additional `h-100` on the `flex-grow-1` to your answer please. Thank you.

Comment: @Barrard I was expecting you would edit the answer and I'll approve so you get 2 points. `:)` No worries it's added now.

Comment: Sorry I'm a newb and forgot I could do that. :P

Comment: @Barrard It's alright, mistakes happen. Have a nice day! `:)`